# Problem after transferring a project from one computer to another Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I built a Unity project on a computer, then moved it to another one that has Xcode on it to build it there. However, during the build process, an error occurred that indicated that the path was unavailable. the path of the build computer was specified there. I was looking for a way to change the file search path, but I didn't find one. [here is an image of the error that occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3C8a.png)

Comment: Was the first machine a Mac too?

Comment: no, it`s Windows first

Comment: Are you using [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/cross-platform-native-plugins-ultra-pack-31086) plugin? Try updating it.